# Input event handling: trigger wont trigger if held (SDL2 in C)

Tags: c, input, sdl-2

I am making a Tank like game, I tried making the tank move when the trigger is activated. To do this I check for events like so (I think this is the root of the problem):

```
 SDL_Event event;
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
    {
        switch (event.type)
        {
            case SDL_QUIT:
                proper_shutdown();
                exit(0);
                break;
            case SDL_CONTROLLERAXISMOTION:
            process_caxis(stick, event, player);        
            break;
         }
```

The process_caxis function is also used for determining the angle of the joysticks, which I will leave out for minimal working example purposes. It is constructed as follows:

```
void process_caxis(stick *stick, SDL_Event event, tank *player)
{   
                if (event.caxis.which == 0)
                            {                                   
                    if (event.caxis.axis == SDL_CONTROLLER_AXIS_TRIGGERRIGHT)
                    {
                        if (event.caxis.value > JOYSTICK_DEAD_ZONE)
                        {
                            move_forward(player, event);
                        }
                    }
                }
}
```

As you can see it calls for the `move_forward();` function, which in itself is constructed as follows:

```
void move_forward(tank *player, SDL_Event event)
{
    player->xvel += (int)-(cos(player->body_angle*PI/180)*(1-event.caxis.value/SDL_CONTROLLER_AXIS_MAX)/1000);
    player->yvel += (int)-(sin(player->body_angle*PI/180)*(1-event.caxis.value/SDL_CONTROLLER_AXIS_MAX)/1000); 
    printf("player x: %d \n player y: %d \n", player->x, player->y);    
}
```

During the making of this post I found out that SDL_CONTROLLER_AXIS_MAX is 6 as opposed to 32767. That shouldn't matter for the problem at hand though.
What I wanted from this function is that the velocity is multiplied by a factor relevant to how hard you pull that trigger. The reality is that you have to spam the trigger to get it moving. I think this is due to the `case SDL_CONTROLLERAXISMOTION` only being true if the trigger value is changed. I am trying to find a way to call my function (`move_forward`) when `if (event.caxis.value > JOYSTICK_DEAD_ZONE)` returns true.

Comment: [SDL_CONTROLLER_AXIS_MAX](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GameControllerAxis) is maximum number of axes, it never meant to be maximum value of single axis. Event method is problemmatic - same as with buttons, quickly spamming events will produce faster movement. In your case you're only interested in moving every gameplay loop iteration, so before moving you need to get axis values via [SDL_GameControllerGetAxis](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GameControllerGetAxis), no events involved (side note - you may want high frequency events to reconstruct precise movement curve; that's not your case)

Comment: I can't find the ' Kudos to you' button so I will do it this way. Thank you for your educated answer you are awesome, don't let people tell you otherwise.